# Android - Other Apps starting an intent on my app calls onDestroy and onCreate instead. of onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile

I have two Apps, let call them App A and App b. I dont have control on App B. its a 3rd party app. App A sends an intent to App B using start activity. App A is in onPause state when this happens. App b starts a new intent (thats how they do it) to respond back. When they start a new intent onDestroy of App A is being called and then onCreate is called. This causes App A's state to be reset.

I can see. this in my adb logcat -b events
10-02 17:36:36.417  5592  5592 I am_on_destroy_called: [0,com.example.testappa.MainActivity,performDestroy]

App B is claiming its industry practice thats how we do . Please guide how i can retain state in App A or any other solutions

I have tried using  onSaveInstanceState method but when its calling onCreate the savedInstanceState is null

Comment: "When they start a new intent onDestroy of App A is being called and then onCreate is called" -- your log statement suggests that you mean that `onDestroy()` of an *activity* is called, and then `onCreate()` of an *activity* is called. An app is not an activity. "Please guide how i can retain state in App A" -- hold the state somewhere other than the activity that is being destroyed and created.

Comment: Try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the `<activity>` manifest entry for  `MainActivity` in your App A and see if that helps.